# How to concat old value with new one in android database

Tags: android

I want to concat old value with new one of the same colum.For example when I update the colum so the first value replace by the new one.So that is why I want to concat the first value with the new one.Like if I have column named "android"
and it contain value "name" and now I want to update this column with value "wiki"
so it replace the value of "android" with value of "wiki".So  thats why I want to sotre both of the value.Like column "android"contain value="name" and "wiki" also in the same column.
I use the coding but it give me syntax error as:

```
      db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME +" SET "+COL_SECOND_2 +"= CONCAT"+
         (COL_SECOND_att_stat+", "+name)+ " WHERE ROLL=?",new String[]
               {roll});
```

If any one want to help please explain with example.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `'` while setting string values.

**Example query.**

`UPDATE COMPANY SET ADDRESS = 'Texas' WHERE ID = 6;`

you didt you `'` in you string.

Comment: what is the proper way in android database

Answer (score 0):

You have to use () after CONCAT and before WHERE like the following..

```
db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME +" SET "+COL_SECOND_2 +"= CONCAT("+
     (COL_SECOND_att_stat+", "+name)+ ") WHERE ROLL=?",new String[]
           {roll});
```

or remove the CONCAT and use ' '

```
db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME +" SET "+COL_SECOND_2 +"= '"+
     (COL_SECOND_att_stat+", "+name)+ "' WHERE ROLL=?",new String[]
           {roll});
```

Comment: db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME,cv, " SET "+COL_SECOND_2 +"= '"+ (COL_SECOND_3+", "+name)+ "'ROLL=?",new String[]{roll});

        return  true;  it show me syntax erro near set

Comment: hello sir it show me syntax error  as 09-29 13:23:58.331 1278-1278/com.example.prince.studentrecord E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "SET": syntax error